# R - xlim sequential increase

Tags: r, sequential

Is it possible to increase the values in the X-axis with 1? For example - 1,2,3,4,5 etc.

Right now I use this:

```
xlim=c(1,16)
```

And the result is:

[image]

Which doesn't look nice, the ideal would be to have a sequential increase with 1 - from 1 to 16, since I have 16 values for the X-axis.

Comment: `plot(1:10, xaxt = "n"); axis(1, 1:10)`

Comment: What Gabor is saying is yes, you have to prevent plotting of the axes and then manually specifying where `at` to put the ticks. You can also format them using the `label` argument.

Comment: Thanks @G.Grothendieck What about if I want to have a sequantial increasement by 5 instead of 1?

Comment: Look at the help for `seq`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xlim` can be finely controlled with `axis`. To make it clear, I will reproduce one plot without axis control and one instead where we performed a modification on the scale.

```
x <- rnorm(100, 10, 2)
y <- rnorm(100, 10, 2)

par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
```

`Plot 1` is produced without axis control

```
plot(x, y, main = "Plot 1")
```

In `Plot 2` we set a demonstrative `xlim` and `ylim` that produce a scale from 0 to 20 for both axes. We can more finely tune it with `axis`: to make an example, I create a scale by 1 for axis `x` and by 5 for axis `y`

```
plot(x, y, xlim = c(0, 20), ylim = c(0, 20), main = "Plot 2")
axis(1, at=seq(0, 20, 1))
axis(2, at=seq(0, 20, 5))
```

[image]

That's not all. `axis` allow a really fine work on your plot axis with its arguments.

```
axis(side, at=, labels=, pos=, lty=, col=, las=, tck=, ...)
```

**side**

an integer indicating the side of the graph to draw the axis (1=bottom, 2=left, 3=top, 4=right)

**at**

a numeric vector indicating where tic marks should be drawn

**labels**

a character vector of labels to be placed at the tickmarks (if NULL, the at values will be used)

**pos**
the coordinate at which the axis line is to be drawn. (i.e., the value on the other axis where it crosses)

**lty**

line type

**col**

the line and tick mark color

**las**

labels are parallel (=0) or perpendicular(=2) to axis

**tck**

length of tick mark as fraction of plotting region (negative number is 
outside graph, positive number is inside, 0 suppresses ticks, 1 creates gridlines) default is -0.01